# windows 10 chrome download wont open file location if windows explorer already open

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10, windows-explorer, download, file-location

In windows 10 I have windows explorer open at any directory.
In chrome I download a program.Once downloaded I click open file location
on the download options at the bottom of chrome.
Nothing happens.
If I close the explorer window it will then work!